# Conditions for equations with common roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Determine the necessary conditions for which two equations of fourth degree have three common roots.

Let $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$ be the common roots, $\alpha$  $(\beta )$, the remaining root of $f=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$  $(g=Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E)$. Then
$\beta-\alpha=\frac{b}{a}-\frac{B}{A}$ and $\frac{\beta }{\alpha }=\frac{E}{A}\cdot \frac{a}{e} $. I couldn't find something useful yet.

Comment: Have you looked at Polynomial GCD calculations on Wikipedia?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor
The three common roots would be the factors of the GCD and of course dividing the polynomials by the GCD would give the extra root.  Phrasing this symbolically should give the conditions.

Comment: @ztefelina -- It's not a problem that makes sense to do by hand, but even with a computer, it's tedious, to say the least. Where does the problem come from? Is it HW? Is it from a textbook? If so, which one?

Comment: @ztefelina The two relations you derived can be solved for $\alpha, \beta$ in terms of the coefficients, then $f(\alpha)=0$ and $g(\beta)=0$ give two necessary conditions. For the rest of roots to be shared, the quotients must only differ by a constant factor, so normalizing the polynomials to monic ones $\frac{1}{a} \cdot \frac{f(x)}{x-\alpha}=\frac{1}{A} \cdot \frac{g(x)}{x-\beta}\,$, which gives four more conditions after identifying the coefficients. None of that is too pretty to calculate in the general case, though, not by hand nor even with a CAS.

Comment: I've recently seen a solution for the second degree equations and I thought that there might exist a 'rule', in order to find the coefficients for higher-degree polynomials, because it's not desirable at all to calculate them using Vieta's formulas.